# is it possible to change bulma's classes color atribute based on a hex value inserted by user?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bulma

I need to create a totally customizable react app, so i want the user to choose the color the aplication will use, then from code I need  to edit bulma's framework classes to set the color the user wants to see in the app.
I have been reading about sass, but i'm not sure.

```
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#b32aa9");//color must be saved in database
  return (
   <div className="App">
   <HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={setColor}/>
   <input type="text" value={color} readOnly/>  const [color, setColor] = useState("#b32aa9");
  return (
   <div className="App">
   <HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={setColor}/>
   <input type="text" value={color} readOnly/>
```

Comment: a sass compiler is typically used at build time.

Comment: Then, what exactly do you mean "the color of the application". Do you mean some sort of themeing? Then you might want to look into [BulmaSwatch](https://jenil.github.io/bulmaswatch/), and build a theme of your liking from there.